# VueJS v-model value in to another input

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I have two inputs, first:

```
<input v-model="from_amount" id="from_amount" type="text" class="form-control" name="from_amount">
```

And the second:

```
<input id="from_amount" type="text" class="form-control" name="to_amount" value="@{{ from_amount }}">
```

If i type number in `from_amount` it should be outputted in `to_amount`

Here's my VueJS code:

```
var request = new Vue({
    el: '#request-creator',
        data: {
            from_amount: '',
            to_amount: ''
        },
        computed: {
            calculate: function() {
                return (this.from_amount * 750) / 0.00024
            }
        }
})
```

But seems like it's impossible to do with Vue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [v-bind](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind), to bind computed property to an input field like following:

```
<input id="from_amount" type="text" class="form-control" name="to_amount" v-bind:value="calculatedFromAmount">
```

or in short, you can also write

```
 ... :value="calculatedFromAmount">
```

See Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bvr9754h/

You have to define computed property like following in due component:

```
    computed: {
        calculatedFromAmount: function() {
            return (this.from_amount * 750) / 0.00024
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you, but how to make it vice versa?

Comment: @AlexanderKim What do you mean vice versa?

Comment: i mean if i type value in `to_amount` then it should be converted back in `from_amount` - it's a currency converter calculator.

Comment: Nice, so we can use 2 `v-model`. Last question: how can i get an option value and use it instead of "7" in your example?

Comment: @AlexanderKim What do you mean `option value`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129501/discussion-between-saurabh-and-alexander-kim).

Answer (score 0):

it's very possible.

Modify your code so that `to_amount` is the name of the computed property :

```
var request = new Vue({
el: '#request-creator',
    data: {
        from_amount: '',
    },
    computed: {
        to_amount: function() {
            return (this.from_amount * 750) / 0.00024
        }
    }
})
```

and the html to :

```
<input id="from_amount" type="text" class="form-control" name="to_amount" :value="to_amount">
```